If I tell my friend to buy and open a product, then return it to the store, then I buy that product at an "open box" price, is that considered fraud?
Based on a Reddit post I read a moment ago:

Sounds shitty but this is an amazing way to get deals at best buy.
Buddy goes in, buys it new, returns it a few hours later.
And boom! Now you have an open box item that you know is perfectly fine at a nice discount!
Normally I'd feel bad as its pretty scummy to do but best buy clearly doesn't give a fuck about their consumers so I'd say it kinda evens out lmao
Saved $350 on a monitor, and another $100 on a headset doing this

I suspect this is fraud, but I'm not certain what specific fraud rule it violates.
This was in the United states, but I'm also curious about Belgium.

"Normally I don't do fraud and theft, but I justify it this time because i want to."

If the firm figured it out, at a minimum, they'd ban you from the store.

Does this scheme really work? I'd have thought that big chain stores would ship returned items back to a depot, not put them back on the shelf for resale.

This is fraud
And a conspiracy to commit fraud.
Details differ slightly by jurisdiction but the essential elements of fraud are:

Deceit
Dishonesty
With the intent to cause someone loss or give yourself financial gain.

They’re all there.

What was the deceipt and dishonesty? Is the customer required to provide a true reason for the return? Does the return policy have restrictions on the acceptable reasons, so that lying about the reason would constitute fraud?

I added a link to Best Buy's return policy to my answer. Which part of it are they violating? Only the third bullet point is correct.

@Barmar Not being required to give a reason when making a return doesn't change the fact that the intent is to have someone else purchase it at a lower price causing the store to lose money.

@JoeW That's what I meant when I said the first bullet point is met. But fraud requires the other factors as well.

@Barmar What other factors? If you are making a comment related to other factors you should include that in your comment and not just bring it up after someone else responds to you.

@JoeW It was in my first comment: "What was the deceipt and dishonesty?" Those are the first two bullet items.

@Barmar are you suggesting that purchasing a product with the sole intention of returning it so someone else can purchase it for below cost isn’t deceitful and dishonest

@JoeW Good point. But unless someone does it regularly, it's practically impossible to distinguish it from "I changed my mind".

@Barmar I don't think anyone is talking about the difficulty of proving it.

@Barmar The deceit comes from the fact that you're pretending to be a genuine customer while in your mind you know you are going to return the item in a used condition so that you can purchase it later for less. The fact that it might be difficult (or even impossible) to prove doesn't change that fact.

I don't think this is illegal.
It's similar to "wardrobing", where you buy fancy clothing for an event, wear it once, and then return it. If the store's return policy simply requires that the item be "like new" and you were careful not to spill anything on it, you're probably in the clear.
In fact, the scheme described in the reddit post is not as bad for the store as wardrobing. Often the returned item is not sellable at all, because most customers don't want used clothing (people who do go to thrift shops and consignment stores, not high-end department stores). But in this case, you go back to the store and repurchase the item, so it's not a total loss to them.
All these practices can be classified as "return policy abuse". But taking advantage of loopholes in a store policy is not usually illegal.
Best Buy's return and exchange policy can be found here. It actually does prohibit wardrobing, because it says

Apparel must not be worn or laundered, and its original tags must be attached for us to accept a return.

but this is probably very difficult for them to enforce (wardrobers know to keep the tags on). But for anything else, it simply says

Items need to be returned in a like-new condition.

There's a short list of products that can't be returned, but that's not really relevant.

The question would be to some extent if buyer one committed fraud, or violated a duty of good faith and fair dealing in the transaction, which true buyer two conspired in. But, a store is only likely to pursue it if it becomes a massive organized scheme, and it has other options (like shipping opened items back to a central warehouse) that undermine its effectiveness without a lawsuit. If it becomes too pervasive, a store can just end its policy of accepting returns.

@ohwilleke There are countries like Australia that have codified the consumer right to return defective goods into law. This is why Steam offers refunds on the video games it sells: they got sued for millions of dollars by the ACCC for violating Australian consumer law.

@nick012000 Perhaps, although this question is asking primarily about U.S. law (I honestly don't know what laws Belgium has regarding returns).

@nick012000 Such laws are probably not relevant to schemes like this, since the product isn't defective. If there were a law stating that products can be returned for any reason, that would matter.

This answer is focussing on the shop's return policy, but that's a distraction. It's not a requirement of fraud that there also be a breach of contract: you can fully comply with the letter of a contract while still committing fraud. The reason why this scenario is fraud is because the first purchaser represents to the shop something untrue (that they intend at the outset to genuinely purchase the item) and they intend by the false representation to make a gain and cause a loss.
